# SSRS Chart: Filtering and controlling axis maximum

Tags: sql-server, reporting-services, ssrs-2008, ssrs-grouping

I am creating a chart off in SSRS based on software version usage per month. I would like to compare how often each version is used per month in comparison to other versions. The image I'm working with is below:

[image]

Obviously with one version being used so highly, it visually skews my data, making the rest of the data harder to see. I am curious if there is any way to do the following things in SSRS:

- Having the user Toggle /select/choose which versions they would like to appear on the chart, with the chart then automatically adjusting its Y-Axis settings
- Having the user adjust the y-axis settings themselves, thus being able to get a closer look or a zoomed out look of the data.

Answer (score 1):

There are a few questions here.

Here's my base report:

[image]

**Parameter-based axis**

You can definitely set axis limits with a parameter. I created a parameter called *AxisLimit* and set **Maximum** property to use this parameter under **Axis Options** -> **Set axis scale and style**:

[image]

Works as required:

[image]

**Filtering by parameter**

You can also set up the report to filter values based on a user selection.

You can apply this to the DataSet in the query text or as a parameter to an underlying stored procedure.

If you need the data elsewhere in the report and can't apply this at the DataSet level, you can set up a filter at the chart level. I set up a multi-value parameter called Groups which contains the groups in the DataSet.

At the report I set the filter as:

[image]

Where the expression is:

```
=IIf(InStr(Join(Parameters!Groups.Value, ",")
  , CStr(Fields!grp.Value)) > 0
  , "INCLUDE", "EXCLUDE")
```

Here I use the `Join` function to get the list of selected parameters values, then filter the DataSet based on these. Again, works as required:

[image]

**Scale breaks**

One option you might not have considered is **Scale Breaks**, which is meant to help with this sort of data:

[image]

[image]

Maybe this will help, too.

Comment: What I do need help on is creating a multi-valued parameter. I understand that in the report in which my chart resides, I need to have this multi-valued parameter in which my Chart's filters refer to, which in turn allow the user to choose which sets of data to see. I do not have any experience with the multi-valued parameter in SSRS (and my coding is weak in SSRS) and tried teaching myself today, but I found myself more confused and lost than anything.